# Using AWS Glue to Convert Zipped csv Files to Parquet Fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a file `myfile.txt.gz` in a bucket in S3.  I am using a Glue job to convert this file to parquet.  The code is shown below.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.ChoiceOption
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.MappingSpec
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.ResolveSpec
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.errors.CallSite
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueArgParser
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JsonOptions
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame 
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._; 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 


object GlueApp {
  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {
    val spark: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
    val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)
    val args = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(sysArgs, Seq("JOB_NAME").toArray)
    Job.init(args("JOB_NAME"), glueContext, args.asJava)
    val truncColUdf = udf((str: String) => if (str.length > 29999) str.substring(0, 29999) else str)

    //myfile
    val datasource21 = glueContext.getCatalogSource(database = "data", tableName = "myfile", redshiftTmpDir = "", transformationContext = "datasource21").getDynamicFrame()
    val revDF21_1 = datasource21.toDF().withColumn("body", truncColUdf(col("body")))
    val truncDynamicFrame21_1 = DynamicFrame(revDF21_1, glueContext)
    val applymapping21 = truncDynamicFrame21_1.applyMapping(mappings = Seq(("id", "bigint","id", "bigint"),
                ("body", "varchar(65535)", "body", "varchar(65535)")), caseSensitive = false, transformationContext = "applymapping21")
    val resolvechoice21 = applymapping21.resolveChoice(choiceOption = Some(ChoiceOption("make_struct")), transformationContext = "resolvechoice21")
    val dropnullfields21 = resolvechoice21.dropNulls(transformationContext = "dropnullfields21")
    val datasink21 = glueContext.getSinkWithFormat(connectionType = "s3", options = JsonOptions("""{"path": "s3://mypath/myfilefolder"}"""), transformationContext = "datasink21", format = "parquet").writeDynamicFrame(dropnullfields21)

    Job.commit()
   }
}
```

When I run this job, I get the error message:

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException ThreadPoolExecutor already shutdown

However, when I run this same exact job but against the same file `myfile.txt` but non-zipped, it works as intended.  I have also tried running without the truncation lines and got the same error.  I am wondering what this error means and why I would be getting it.

EDIT: After more testing, I think the error is caused by the the truncation because all files that do not require truncation work. One thing I can think of that may cause issues is since all the files are zipped, it is unable to read the columns to execute the truncation function. Could anyone confirm this and possibly offer up workarounds? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it the only error in logs? Is there a stack trace to understand the origin?

Comment: After more testing, I think the error is caused by the the truncation because all files that do not require truncation work.  One thing I can think of that may cause issues is since all the files are zipped, it is unable to read the columns to execute the truncation function.  Could anyone confirm this and possibly offer up workarounds? Thank you in advance.